# Get Only Values from a Map to an array

Tags: typescript, collections

I want to get values of a map and store inside a string array in typescript.

```
myMap= [0:'Mohit',1:'Balesh',2:'Jatin'];
arr[];
```

Expected Result `arr['Mohit','Balesh','Jatin']`

Comment: Your example code is not valid typescript, `[0: 'Mohit']` is not valid array syntax. Do you mean `{ 0: 'Mohit' }` (objects) instead?

Answer (score 11):

To get an array from the values in a map you can spread the map values into an array using the Javascript spread operator (...) with the values() method of map.

```
yourArray = [...myMap.values()]

// gives the array ['Mohit', 'Balesh', 'Jatin']
```

Answer (score 7):

Map.values() returns a MapIterator object which can be converted to Array using Array.from:

```
let values = Array.from( myMap.values() );
// ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your `myMap` is not valid.
It should look like this:

```
myMap= {0:'Mohit',1:'Balesh',2:'Jatin'};
```

And getting an array from it should look like this:

```
myArr = Object.values(myMap);
```

Comment: Brother Is this Valid in Typescript

Comment: Yes, you can try it.

Comment: Sorry Brother Still on consoling it gives ["0: 'Mohit'", "1: 'Balesh'"].